# Django redis caching per url

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-redis

So I am trying to implement moreover learn how to cache Django views per URL. I am able to do so and here is what is happening...

1. I visit a URL for 1st time and Django sets the caches.
2. I get my result from cache and not from querying the database during the second visit if the browser is same.

Now the doubt is -  if I change my browser from the first visit and second visit, for example, do the first visit from Chrome (it sets the cache) and during the second visit from Mozilla, it again sets the cache. I was expecting it to return the result from the cache.

During my research on StackOverflow and checking what it sets as cache, I found there are two important things first being a header and the second being the content. And I think every time a browser is changed the header is new so it sets the cache instead of returning the result from cache. Do let me know if I am wrong.

I have a public URL and I was thinking to show data from the cache if a subsequent request is made, irrespective of browser or mobile/laptop/desktop, only based on Url, is that anyhow possible?

**(I was thinking if someone from the north part of the country visit a URL, subsequent visit to the same URL from the south part of the country should get data from the cache, based on my cache expiry time though)

Also if my understanding is wrong please correct me.

I am learning to cache using Redis on Django.

Answer (score 0):

So i manually set key for some of my public url(views), adjust cache on create and delete and during get-list I check for the key values in cache, get the result from cache if cache timeout or unavailable then get the result from database. Somehow response time for this is little bit slower than cache_page(), the default django function, I dont know why. Any explanation ?? or Am i correct ?